# Plot multiple simultaneous animated subplots with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

My goal is to plot animated Lissajous figures simultaneously animated with matplotlib's module *animation*, however I am not being able to control all the subplots.I wanted to use as little code as possible and so recurred to some for loops so as to plot as many figures as I want in a very neat and rapid. Here's my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation as an

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3)
lines = np.array([[i.plot([], []) for i in ax[j]] for j in range(len(ax))])

for i in range(len(lines)):
    for j in range(len(lines[i])):
        axnow = ax[i][j]
        axnow.set_xlim(-1, 1)
        axnow.set_ylim(-1, 1)

xdata = [[[] for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]
ydata = [[[] for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]


def animate(frame):
    w = 1
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        for j in range(len(lines[i])):
            xdata[i][j].append(np.cos(w * frame))
            ydata[i][j].append(np.sin(1 * frame))
            line = lines[i][j][0]
            line.set_data(xdata[i][j], ydata[i][j])
            w += 1

    return lines


an.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, blit=True, frames=np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 1000), repeat=False,
interval=20)


plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

However, nothing is really displayed and I don't know where my mistake is. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to store the animation class in a variable, else it's being garbage collected right away. `ani = animation.FuncAnimation(...)`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I tried that but I'm still getting some weird error. Also, could you explore more on why do we have to store the animation class in a variable? I don't really understand why

Comment: In python objects that are not hold in a variable are garbage collected (simply speaking). So if you jsut write `MyClass(1,2)` it will be gone shortly after. But if you write `firstclass = MyClass(1,2)` it will be stored in the variable `firstclass`.